# How does flatMap work on Maps in scala? map can be used as mapValues on Maps but how does the flatMap function work on Map objects?

Tags: scala, dictionary, flatmap

I am not able to understand the functioning of flatMap function on Map objects.

Comment: any specific example you strangling with and happy to share??

Comment: For more details: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#flatMap[B](f:A=>scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B]):List[B]

Comment: Guys, don't downvote without explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You use flatMap if you want to flatten your result from map-function.
keep in mind:

```
flatMap(something)
```

is identical to

```
map(something).flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a value or a key in the Map having a list then it can be flatMap-ed.

Example:

`val a = Map(1->List(1,2),2->List(2,3))`

`a.map(_._2)` gives `List(List(1,2),List(2,3))`

you can flatten this using flatMap => `a.flatMap(_._2)` or `a.map(_._2).flatten` gives `List(1,2,2,3)`

src: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/12158.html

Not sure about any other way of using flatMap on a Map though.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is good question, cause map cannot be flatten as other collections. First off all we should look at the signature of this method:

```
def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): Map[B]
```

So, the documentation says that it should return **Map**, but it is not true, cause it can return any **GenTraversableOnce** and not only it. We can see it in the provided examples:

```
def getWords(lines: Seq[String]): Seq[String] = lines flatMap (line => line split "\\W+")

// lettersOf will return a Seq[Char] of likely repeated letters, instead of a Set
def lettersOf(words: Seq[String]) = words flatMap (word => word.toSet)

// lettersOf will return a Set[Char], not a Seq
def lettersOf(words: Seq[String]) = words.toSet flatMap (word => word.toSeq)

// xs will be an Iterable[Int]
val xs = Map("a" -> List(11,111), "b" -> List(22,222)).flatMap(_._2)

// ys will be a Map[Int, Int]
val ys = Map("a" -> List(1 -> 11,1 -> 111), "b" -> List(2 -> 22,2 -> 222)).flatMap(_._2)
```

So let look at the full signature:

```
def flatMap[B, That](f: ((K, V)) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Map[K, V], B, That]): That
```

Now we see it returns **That** - something that implicit **CanBuildFrom** can provide for us.

You can find many explanation how **CanBuildFrom** works.
But the main idea is put some function from your **key** -> **value** pair to **GenTraversableOnce**, it can be some **Map**, **Seq** or even **Option** and it will be **mapped** and **flattened**. Also you can provide your own **CanBuildFrom**.